# Cannot pick and append list elements into a existing csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with the following format

```
Mylist = [['5AEEP1','0','1','LAP1'],['5XXEP1','0','1','LAP2'],['5AXAP1','0','1','LAP3']]
```

**I am trying to get the first and last element and append them into an existing csv**

```
5AEEP1,LAP1
5XXEP1,LAP2
5AXAP1,LAP3
```

with the following

```
with open(old_pcodes,"a",encoding='utf-8', newline="") as infile:         
    writer = csv.writer(infile, delimiter=';',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    towrite =[]
    for ritem in Mylist:
        if ritem:
            pno = ritem[0]
            thepcode = ritem[3]
            finalout = pno+';'+thepcode
            finalout.strip('"')
        writer.writerow([finalout])
```

I get an escape error

If I add

```
writer = csv.writer(infile, delimiter=';',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
```

Then I have in the csv a space

```
5AEEP1 ,LAP1
5XXEP1 ,LAP2
5AXAP1 ,LAP3
```

How else can I do it

Comment: I had the impression that writerow([ritem[0], ritem[3]]) will place them in new row

Comment: @PatrickArtner you mean writer.writerows((i[0],i[3]) for i in Mylist) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write them [with `writerows(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) all at once:

```
import csv

Mylist = [['5AEEP1','0','1','LAP1'],['5XXEP1','0','1','LAP2'],['5AXAP1','0','1','LAP3']]

with open("t.txt","a",encoding='utf-8', newline="") as infile:         
    writer = csv.writer(infile, delimiter=';',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerows( (i[0],i[3]) for i in Mylist )

with open("t.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
5AEEP1;LAP1
5XXEP1;LAP2
5AXAP1;LAP3
```